# What does this jQuery line mean?

Tags: jquery

```
return $('<div>', {
       class: "my_Class"
 });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's returning a newly created `<div class="my_Class"></div>` element, this is the
[`$(html, props)` overload of `$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).  It takes the element HTML and an object of properties to set.

Something to note though, `class` is a keyword in IE and will cause issues, you need to put it in quotes:

```
return $('<div>', { 'class': "my_Class" });
```

A more complete example may be something like:

```
return $('<div>', { 'class': "my_Class", click: function() { alert('hi'); } });
```

From the docs:

> As of jQuery 1.4, we can pass a map of properties to the second argument. This argument accepts a superset of properties that can be passed to the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) method. Furthermore, any [event type](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: [val](http://api.jquery.com/val), [css](http://api.jquery.com/css), [html](http://api.jquery.com/html), [text](http://api.jquery.com/text), [data](http://api.jquery.com/data), [width](http://api.jquery.com/width), [height](http://api.jquery.com/height), or [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset). Note that Internet Explorer will not allow you to create an input element and change its type; you must specify the type using `<input type="checkbox" />` for example.

Comment: Another question: is it equivalent to:                               var element = document.createElement('div'); 
 element.setAttribute("class","my_class"); 
 return element;  ?

Comment: @UmairP - *almost*, yes, except the version in the question returns a jQuery object wrapping that document fragment, the version in your comment will return a DOM element directly.